# Lazarus. And в большом условии

Tags: pascal, if

Создаю пятнашки на паскаль, язык изучаю недавно
Есть данное условие:

```
if(Button1.Top = 0) and (Button1.Left = 112) then begin
          if((Button2.Top <> 0) and (Button2.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button3.Top <> 0) and (Button3.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button4.Top <> 0) and (Button4.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button5.Top <> 0) and (Button5.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button6.Top <> 0) and (Button6.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button7.Top <> 0) and (Button7.Left <> 0)) and
          ((Button8.Top <> 0) and (Button8.Left <> 0)) then begin
               Button1.Left := 0;
               end
```

Оно в теории должно проверять есть ли на данной координате пятнашка. Но из-за того, что на координатной оси X или Y могут стоять другие пятнашки, он выдает FALSE.

Как скомбинировать условия `((Button2.Top <> 0) and (Button2.Left <> 0))`, чтобы два условия считались вместе, а не проверялись программой по-отдельности?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.  А вообще все это выглядит как неправильно спроектированное.

Comment: Я уже решил проблему

Comment: Как бы то ни было, строить логику на основе координат визуальных контролов - неправильно. Должна быть внутренняя структура данных, хранящая состояние. Если нужно двигать контролы - на основе этого состояния. Сигнал об изменении состояния может приходить от контролов. Получается, однако, MVC модель, на зря её придумали.